# Can't get a parameter in struts 2 from jsp... why?

Tags: jsp, struts2

I'm trying to execute an action with the next URL

```
http://localhost:8080/FantasticWebsite/services/addPhone?id=6
```

So my parameter object must have at least the key "id" with value "6", but no!, I get all parameters in my form but that ID don't appears.

Im getting parameters with this :

```
id=Integer.parseInt(parameter.get("id")[0]);
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: And why do you getting parameters with that?

Comment: Why don't you just use an `id` action property?

Comment: Are you using a `POST` method? Normally you should avoid mixing query strings and POST payloads.

Comment: How do you get all parameters in the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
String id = getRequest().getParameter("id");
```

where

```
    protected HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
        return ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    }
```

Comment: @rafuru Why are you bypassing the normal S2 parameter mechanisms?